# Could not use the standard linking in my app

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have just updated the new Uber app (January 8, 2018) and the deep linking is not working.

Could you explain more?

Below is my code:

```
   formattedUrl = String.format("uber://action=setPickup&client_id=%s&dropoff[latitude]=%f&dropoff[longitude]=%f", 
    mClientId, http://to.lat , to.lng);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse(formattedUrl);
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(uri);

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    mContext.startActivity(i);
```

With the old version of Uber app, my code works well. It shows the correct the pickup & drop off location but in the new app, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

May be they have updated things on this in their application.

You can generate deep link using this [link](https://developer.uber.com/products/ride-requests-deeplink).